# How to use Custom Date Picker for Different Activities?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I created a custom date picker with 3 buttons as I wished. 
Now I need use this DatePicker for different activities..

I cant able to find the right way to use it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parent class Which extends Activity and has this method to create DatePicker.. Then Extend  this for all Activies which needs DatePicker..

Something like this..

```
class MyDIalog extends Activity {
         @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   public void createDatePicker(){
  //code to create Date Picker
  }
}
```

And your ACtvity will be

```
class MyAct extends MyDIalog {


}
```

Comment: it worked out well... but getting only Month Day Year, not the view as Weeks of month as shown in Default one.. can u suggest for this too.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is creating an Activity for DatePicker. You can make DatePicker Activity `transparent` by adding the attribute below to activity node in manifest file:

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Then you should use `startActivityForResult()` to start DatePicker Activity. When user select date and click to OK button, you can use `setResult()` before finishing activity:

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("date", date);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

The last operation is handling `onActivityResult()` in the first activity.